# How to automate the payment gateway integrated with the module with dynamic order ID?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium latest version in the pom.xml file
what I need to automate the normal purchase flow

**Steps to purchase**

1. login with dummy mobile number with dummy OTP
2. redirected to Buy module, customer will enter the amount
3. click on proceed it will redirect to the buy summary screen(where customer verify the amount etc)
4. It will redirect the customer to the cashfree payment gateway with URL- https://payments-test.cashfree.com/order/#nxRLuznqit8ZMOCHwT8o
5. In this URL #nxRLuznqit8ZMOCHwT8o is randomly generated everytime
6. I tried to get the id of Proceed to Payment from the elements in URL - https://payments-test.cashfree.com/order/#nxRLuznqit8ZMOCHwT8o

but when I run the selenium script point number 6 is not working

**My questing is**

**How do I get the Id of buttons(from cashfree URL) and successful proceed to pay button when we are dealing with payment gateway?**

Cashfree site
[image]